# How to take the input for next page by using previous page response in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, parameter-passing

I need to take the input for next page from previous page source.

Previous page source:
[image]

In next page I need to pass this departure city as input in URL.

Sample URL:
/findflight?depart=Acapulco

Here I want to pass the Departure city's(previous page) in next page URL.

So, how can I parameterized this in jmeter??

Let me know if anyone need any additional info on this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "Post Processor" like "Regular Expression Extractor" or Boundary Extractor and then pass it in the next sampler path as ${varSam}

Below is a sample where I am using Regular Expression extractor to fetch a value and putting it in a variable. So, this is your request from where you have to fetch the departure city.
[image]

Here I am passing that variable in the URL
[image]

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above HTML
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image: JMeter CSS/JQuery Extractor]
3. You will get a **random** city stored as `depart` variable and will be able to access its value as `${depart}` where required

   [image: JMeter CSS/JQuery in action]

Optionally you can extract **all** the values by setting "Match No." to `-1`, this will give you the following variables:

[image: JMeter CSS Jquery getting all matches]

See [How to Use the CSS/JQuery Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) for more information if needed

Comment: Is there any way to take the value in between left boundary and right boundary. Because in the page source there are multiple values are there.

And I followed your steps but in the body it is not parsing the value..

`POST data:
depart=${depart}&departDate=05-23-2018&arrive=Acapulco&returnDate=05-24-2018&numPassengers=1&seatPref=None&seatType=Coach&findFlights.x=93&findFlights.y=16&findFlights=Submit`

Comment: 1. Try upper-case "option" like: `SELECT[NAME=depart] > OPTION`. 2. If you're having `-1` as `Match no.` you need to use `${depart_1}` or `${depart_2}` or whatever. 3. There is a [Boundary Value Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter) available since JMeter 4.0

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved by using the Post Processor(Regular expression extractor). Applied this to the page response.
Page response
[image: Page response]

parameterized this as following:
[image: Regular expression extarctor]

Request for the next page by using the above parameterized value
[image: Request for the next page by using the above parameterized value]

Thanks for the help!!